# execute sp_executesql over length in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My SQL Server version is SQL Server 2008 R2.

There are about 100 rows in the `in` statement.

I use this SQL to do a dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @DynamicDate nvarchar(100) 
DECLARE @SQLString_1 nvarchar(max)

SET @DynamicDate='20181021'
SET @SQLString_1 =  
     N'select  *    
 from T1_'+@DynamicDate+' w      
 left join      
 T2 c      
 on w.ASSET_ID=c.DEVICE_ID      
 left join      
 T3 cm      
 on c.DEVICE_ID=cm.ASSET_ID      
 left join      
 T4 gm      
 on cm.GROUP_ID=gm.GROUP_ID      
 left join      
 T5 em      
 on w.EVENT_ID =em.EVENT_ID      
 and w.EVENT_CATEGORY_ID=em.EVENT_CATEGORY_ID      
 left join T6 sa      
 on w.PROCESS_NAME=sa.PROCESS_NAME
 where 
 w.ASSET_ID in (''{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'',
''{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'',
''{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'',
''{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'',
   ……
''{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'',
''{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'',
''{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'',
''{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'',
''{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}''
)
 '
print(@SQLString_1)
--EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString_1
```

When I print the sql.
The output likes this:

```
select                   
 *    
 from T1_20181021 w      
 left join      
 T2 c      
 on w.ASSET_ID=c.DEVICE_ID      
 left join      
 T3 cm      
 on c.DEVICE_ID=cm.ASSET_ID      
 left join      
 T4 gm      
 on cm.GROUP_ID=gm.GROUP_ID      
 left join      
 T5 em      
 on w.EVENT_ID =em.EVENT_ID      
 and w.EVENT_CATEGORY_ID=em.EVENT_CATEGORY_ID      
 left join T6 sa      
 on w.PROCESS_NAME=sa.PROCESS_NAME
 where 
 w.ASSET_ID in (
'{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}',
'{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}',
  ……
'{XXXXXXXX-XXXX
```

Only a part of it was printed.

When I use `sp_executesql @SQLString_1`

The error is:

> Message 105, level 15, state 1, and line 96 The quote is not closed after the string '{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'.
>   Message 102, level 15, state 1, line 96 There is an incorrect syntax in the vicinity of '{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'.

I had used the keyword `max` in `@SQLString_1`,

So I can't use execute sp_executesql`, it doesn't seem to work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please explain how you come to conclusion that "it doesn't work". Are you getting an error message? If so, please include that in your question. Are you not getting desired results from the query? If so, please demonstrate that the query is supposed to give the desired results with a data set to query over.

Comment: Message 105, level 15, state 1, and line 96

The quote is not closed after the string '{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'.
Message 102, level 15, state 1, line 96
There is an incorrect syntax in the vicinity of '{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'.

Comment: I notice that you have `where 
 w.ASSET_ID in ...` without parentheses, don't know how you got that from the dynamic sql generation but you should get `where 
 w.ASSET_ID in (...)`.

Comment: I have edited my question,in fact,it has parentheses.

Comment: What is the data type of `T1_20181021.ASSET_ID`?

Comment: If it is a GUID, I think you have to format as `'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'`, without the curly braces.

Comment: `T1_20181021.ASSET_ID` is nvarchar(200)

Comment: In fact,the data  in `ASSET_ID` has curly braces.

Comment: And you have doubly and triply checked that there are no missing quotes anywhere? Have you tried generating the query with just one identifier in the list `IN (...)`? What is the message then? Try expanding a bit with more identifiers... still the same problem or at what point do you get the error? Do you have any GUIDs with single quotes in them by mistake? Also, you should store GUIDs using the [`UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) datatype, not using `NVARCHAR`. You're wasting space and resources now.

Comment: Without getting into the string length issue, have you considered dumping all of those `ASSET_ID` values into a `#TempTable`, and then just joining to it? You'll almost certainly get better performance than using an `IN` clause with 100+ `NVARCHAR` values to compare row by row.

Comment: As a bonus, a temp table would also eliminate the string length issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the printing part of your question, `print` is limited to 4000 symbols. If you want to dump longer text in the console, you can print it on chunks like this:

```
print substring(@SQLString_1,    1, 4000)
print substring(@SQLString_1, 4001, 4000)
print substring(@SQLString_1, 8001, 4000)
```

Add as many 4k chunks as needed. Each command will print its chunk on a new line, so your query will be scrambled a bit, but these extra line breaks are easy to find and fix:

> left join T6 sa
>    on w.PROCES  <-- Find this place and join the lines together, to get the original query
>
> S_NAME=sa.PROCESS_NAME
>
> where

About the query error, your query string looks to be converted to non-max type, thus truncated to 4000 chars. Check your concatenations. Cast your non-max parts to nvarchar(max) if necessary.

Comment: I split `ASSET_ID` into two segments to execute. There is 50 {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX} in each segment.There are no mistakes in each part,but it doesn't work when put them together.

Comment: Probably because when you split, the total length is <= 4000, while when put them together becomes longer than 4000 chars.

Comment: The maximum of nvarchar(max) is (2 ^ 31 - 1 - 2) / 2 = 1'073'741'822 double-byte characters.It's impossible to go beyond the scope.

Comment: Up to 2 GB of data. But what I suspect is that during the construction of your query, you get a result, which **isn't** nvarchar(max), but nvarchar(4000), thus it gets truncated. Check your concatenations. Just convert all parts as nvarchar(max) if your aren't sure which one causes the conversion.

Comment: OK,but in my sql,where should I modify?

Comment: @Rhaegal Try make the date variable a NVARCHAR(MAX) as well. Also, for NVARCHARs it's best to have `N` in front of your string literals as well. You can always check the length of the resulting sql string as well (LEN(str)).